# React ref: what is equal to document.querySelectorAll

Tags: reactjs, ref

I have just started with React refs, and I would like to select all icons of ref=this.contentRef.
With js I would do it like this: document.querySelectorAll('.content i'). How to do this with the ref?

```
someMethode() {
  const content = this.contentRef.current.childNodes;
  const content2 = document.querySelectorAll('.content i');
}

render() {
  return (
    <div ref={this.contentRef} className="content">
      <div>
        <i className="fa fa-square" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <i className="fa fa-square" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <i className="fa fa-square" />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The right way is:

```js
 <MyComponent ref={(c) => this.myComponent = c} /> // then check when this.myComponent is NOT undefined
```

The problem resides on WHAT you want to do with the refs. It is super useful when calling child methods or making calculations (render size etc etc) for all the remaining cases there are alternative patterns that will do the job without refs

Comment: This can have issues where it will be null -- it's a caveat where the component mounts and unmounts with each update. "If the ref callback is defined as an inline function, it will get called twice during updates, first with null and then again with the DOM element. This is because a new instance of the function is created with each render, so React needs to clear the old ref and set up the new one. You can avoid this by defining the ref callback as a bound method on the class, but note that it shouldn’t matter in most cases." [source](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)

Comment: You have to check that is not null or undefined, then no issue will occur. Perform those checks when trying to access to a ref is a common pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can actually use QuerySelectorall with ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this)
try something like this

```
const node = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
// Get child nodes
if (node instanceof HTMLElement) {
const child = node.querySelector('.someClass');
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, this is deprecated in react@16.6

https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/10/23/react-v-16-6.html#deprecations-in-strictmode